# How to use parameter to controller job post build action in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am creating a free style jenkins job and use some post build actions such as: `deploy to dropbox`, `deploy to s3` etc. I want to build two boolean parameters for this job to control whether deploy build results to `drop box` or `s3`. For example, if user trigger this job but he doesn't select the `s3` parameter, I don't want to trigger the `s3` post action. How can I achieve this in Jenkins? I didn't find there is any configurations for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using [Flexible Publish Plugin.](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin)

1. You need to install the above plugin in your Jenkins.
2. Then create a freestyle job that will control your choices, that is whether you want to build only `Deploy to S3`  in the post build or only want to build `Deploy to Dropbox` in the post build or you want to trigger both the build at once.
3. In this job create two choice parameters, `DEPLOY_TO_S3` and `DEPLOY_TO_DROPBOX` both with choices YES and NO.

[image]

4.Then in the Post-build Actions section choose the `Flexible Publish Plugin` and do the following configurations and save the job.

[image]

[image]

5. Now build your job with parameters and select YES to trigger the down-steam jobs and No to not to trigger the down-stream jobs.

[image]

And you are done :)